# How to use Telugu font in android TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to display some values which is in Telugu Font. When Iam testing, I found some wrong pronunciation's. I just followed the below code line to display the Telugu font.

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/DroidSansRegionalAAD.ttf");
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myFont);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Can any one help me

Comment: Just a guess but this could be as a result of the encoding of your source data. Where are you getting the text from and how are you reading the source data?

Comment: Just for my test, I edited strings.xml file and added telugu data init. I am just reading from there.

Comment: <string name="a1">ఈ నెల 19న జరగనున్న రాష్ట్రపతి ఎన్నికలకు టీడీపీ దూరం కానుంది. ఓటింగ్ లో పాల్గొనకూడదని నిర్ణయం తీసుకుంది. ఈ విషయంపై టీడీపీ అధికారకంగా ప్రకటించింది.</string>

Comment: Indian fonts are not supported by android. It just jumbles up the words or draws the char wrongly. I have had the same problem with no solution yet. And I tried for Tamil. But it explains it all.

Comment: Thanks Andro, I saw couple of telugu apps like Telugu Bible. They just works fine with out any wrong pronunciations.